# Nexus blob size to big after crash

Tags: nexus, sonatype

So i use nexus OSS for private repo purposes now we ran into an issue where the disk got out of space and after long hours of debugging we were able to recover. However now it seems that my blob store is bigger then it should by at least 100GB.

This repo is the main culprit:

```
"maven-releases": {
  "reclaimableBytes": 0,
  "totalBytes": 170605745239
}
```

See how it's pretty much 150GB big while i completely deleted the repo and emptied it (I did run the compact blob store task)

[image]

In the above screenshot you can see my total blob size, which should be under or around 10GB at this moment. Any body an idea how i can clean that repo and everything in it even though it's not visible in nexus?

It feels like the blob store and component database are out of sync.

Just as FYI this is a raw repo and not an actual maven repo.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try running a "Repair - Reconcile component database from blob store" scheduled task, followed by a compact blobstore task.

Comment: I tried that one already without luck.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-17740.  If that's right, you can follow that ticket for progress on an eventual fix.